# what is difference between lock() and guard() after lock_guard

Tags: c++, boost, mutex

Hi I'm up to code a circular buffer through c++ boost library. and I have come up with some questions that I can't understand.

```
boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard( Mutex );
boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock( Mutex );
```

This is my first time using boost library so I don't really understand what is difference between these two. please help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're conceptually same as:

```
int i(0);
int j(0);
```

This declares `i` and `j` as variables of type `int`, and initializes them with `0`.

Same with this:

```
boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard( Mutex );
boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock( Mutex );
```

This declares `guard` and `lock` as variables of type `boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex>`, and initializes them with `Mutex`. Simple.

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference -  `lock` and `guard` are just the variables names.

You're declaring variables of type `boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex>` and initializing them with the variable `Mutex`. The first one is called `guard` and the second one is called `lock`.

If you write them both next to each other like that then there is one difference in the behaviour you'll see:  The first one should eventually get the mutex lock, if it isn't already locked by the current thread, but the second one will deadlock, because you can't lock a `boost::mutex` twice.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing, you have just named the first one `guard` and the second one `lock`.

Answer (score 1):

these are only two different named variables with the same type:boost::lock_guard, they work both as a guard lock which will be release when leaving current scope.